# How to verify page title in selenium using keyword framework

Tags: selenium, frameworks, keyword

What should be the keyword,object type,object name & value to verify page title in selenium using keyword framework.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer below if it can be used for your issue:

```
// Method to get title and verify with expected
public static void AssertEqualsTitle(WebDriver driver, String expectedTitle) {
    String actualText = driver.getTitle();
    Assert.assertTrue(actualText.toLowerCase().contains(expectedTitle.toLowerCase()));
}
```

Comment: This method is known but need something related to keyword framework to verify my title